# Create a 'remove div' link

Tags: javascript, jquery

With this code I'm able to add a div with some text and and hyperlink inside the div:

```
$('<div/>')
    .html("<a href='#'>x</a> " + i.item.label + " - ")
    .attr({ 'id': i.item.val })
    .addClass('boxClass')
    .appendTo('#acResults');
```

I'd like to remove the created link when I click on the `x` link inside the created div. Something similar to the remove tag in the tags section of this site.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the element is appended dynamically you would need to use a delegated event handler. From there you can use `closest()` to find the parent `div` and remove it. Try this:

```
$('#acResults').on('click', '.boxClass a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.boxClass').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this : add click event using `.on()` (we do it for dynamically created element) and use `.remove()` to remove clicked link.

```
$(document).on('click','div.boxClass a',function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**EDIT** - as OP mentioned "I'd like to remove the created link when I click on the x link inside the created div" in the post, but it looks like OP want to remove `div` and not the link. Please find below updated answer -

```
$(document).on('click','div.boxClass a',function(){
     $(this).closest('div.boxClass').remove();
 });
```

Comment: This removes the link, but not the `.boxClass` parent div. @Rory McCrossan has the correct approach.

Comment: as OP mentioned "I'd like to remove the created link when I click on the x link inside the created div", so I interpreted to remove link only and not div. But OP accepted @RoryMcCrossan answer, so it is confirm that OP wants to remove div and not link. Let me update it in answer

Comment: It would make no practical sense to leave empty DIV's behind. Do not always take questions literally. :) I have removed my DV as you have edited.

Answer (score 0):

add some class to this link

```
$('<div/>')
  .html("<a class='remove-link' href='#'>x</a> " + i.item.label + " - ")
  .attr({'id': i.item.val})
  .addClass('boxClass')
  .appendTo('#acResults');
```

and then try

```
$('.remove-link').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: If there are multiple `.remove-link` on the page, this will re-add the handlers. You really needed to use a delegated event handler (like the other answers). This also leaves an empty div behind.